# Article devant un surnom

Tags: articles, surnoms

*Les embrouilles de Calma* de Barry Jonsberg :

> Imaginez **un pitbull** ayant avalé une guêpe, et vous aurez une idée de
> l'expression qu'arborait Mlle Plait quand elle est entrée dans notre
> classe (...)
>
> -- À propos de quoi ? a-t-elle (*) murmuré en tournant lentement le visage vers moi.
>
> -- De Mlle Plait, tiens !
>
> -- Qui ça ?
>
> -- (...), la prof d'anglais sortie droit des Enfers, **le Pitbull** !

(*) Vanessa

Par la suite, dans tout le livre, on appelle l'enseignante *le Pitbull*. Est-il aussi possible d'omettre l'article dans son surnom ? À mon avis, ce serait plus logique, car *Pitbull* deviendrait son nom.

Comment: Si on donne un surnom à quelqu'un, on garde l'article. Par exemple: Après la primaire de la droite, la femme politique de 54 ans avait été appelée "La taupe" par Aurore Bergé, députée membre de LREM. https://www.gala.fr/l_actu/news_de_stars/valerie-pecresse-traitresse-la-taupe-ces-surnoms-quelle-aimerait-oublier_489762

Answer (score 3):

Il n'y a pas de règle absolue pour les surnoms/sobriquets mais la présence d'un article est plus courante (Le Tigre, Le Sphynx, Le Professeur, Le petit Nicolas, Le Blaireau, etc.) sauf si le surnom reprend un mot qui en est normalement dépourvu (Babar, Tonton, Bécassine, Jupiter).

Sans article, *Pitbull !* pourrait être utilisé mais ce serait souvent plus comme insulte que comme surnom.

Comment: Avec  ou sans article, le mot serait une insulte.

Comment: @Lambie Ou pas. Un surnom, aussi insultant qu'il puisse être, n'est pas forcément une insulte.

Comment: Pit bull. : an aggressive and tenacious person https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pit%20bull#:~:text=2%20%3A%20an%20aggressive%20and%20tenacious%20person

Comment: @Lambie Je sais ce qu'est un pitbull, au sens propre et au sens figuré, merci.

Comment: I don't understand how you can **claim** is not always an insult. And it's pit bull, made into a nickname Pit Bull. Pitbull written together is a rapper's name. En français: pit-bull https://chien.ooreka.fr/chien/voir/643323/pit-bull Encore Mr. Rigoureau qui se trompe.

Comment: @Lambie On se fiche de l'orthographe anglaise. En français, l'orthographe recommandée de pitbull est sans trait d'union, c'est aussi [la plus courante](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pitbull%2Cpit-bull%2Cpit+bull&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3)

Comment: Et un surnom n'est pas nécessairement un insulte. Une insulte, c'est quand on s'adresse à quelqu'un. Ici, les élèves nomment leur prof comme ça, mais ne lui disent pas en face.

Comment: It is always an insult. That's the whole point of calling a teach a pit bull.  Lots of nasty nicknames are insults which are not used directly to someone's face.

Comment: @Lambie *Blaireau !* est toujours une insulte, *Le Blaireau* peut être un surnom non péjoratif. Dans le livre, il ne fait aucun doute que "le Pitbull" est péjoratif, mais tant que ce n'est pas ouvertement dit à cette professeure, ce n'est pas une insulte, ce n'est qu'un surnom.  Je n'ai de toute façon pas compris à quoi rime ton premier commentaire, à part à lancer une nouvelle discussion interminable et sans grand intérêt.

Comment: My first comment means: Si tu dis le mot pit bull avec ou sans article, c'est une insulte. //Why don't you address this directly? "car Pitbull deviendrait son nom". As if Pitbull could be: Jean, Marie.  "Ah, Pitbull, vous êtes là !". Really? I don't think so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135122/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lambie).

Answer (score 1):

À l'extérieur de l'alternative « avec ou sans », oui, en répétant le nom « Mlle » :

> — (...), la prof d'anglais sortie droit des Enfers, Mlle («) *Pitbull*
> (») !

Je ne vois pas de grande nuance, c'est l'association à une race de chien pour l'*agressivité* ou la présomption de *férocité* ; comme on l'a dit [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50001/26366), un surnom n'est pas une interjection ni même toujours une substitution au nom de la personne : c'est le sens de [*surnom*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/surnom). Mais comme on sait déjà qu'il s'agit de *Mlle Plait*, les guillemets seraient facultatifs, si possiblement moins poli ou clair, et on aurait pu avoir recours à l'italique (à l'écrit il va sans dire, même si ça se mime moins bien...).